# How to manage correctly django dependencies for futere deploys

Tags: django, dependencies, setup-project

I'm starting python in the world, but I come from PHP and I'm used to the composer to manage my project dependencies.

In django I'm installing my project dependencies with easy_install. but my question is this: if the environment where I will run my project does not have these dependencies, there is some tool that allows me to easily handle with dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best things is to use pip and virualenv

see here http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/

Then your all problems will be solved

Comment: Yes, pip is the way to go. virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are useful additions, but also require your sys admin to know how to configure web server for them (easily solved with numerous hosting companies).

Comment: Notably, using ``pip freeze > requirements.txt`` makes it simple to then ``pip install -r requirements.txt`` during deployment.

Comment: thanks, the only thing about virtualenv and windows was the MySQLDB package but [this tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/sivasubramaniam3/setup-a-new-virtualenv-for-django-in-windows) was great help